# Rolle's theorem for a function continuous on an open interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If a function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f(a)=f(b)$, then $f'$ is $0$ somewhere on $(a,b)$.

If we merely require $f$ to be continuous on $(a,b)$, then the theorem fails because $f$ could have a "jump" at $a$, and so the value of $f$ at $a$ could be vastly different from the value of $f$ in right-neighborhoods of $a$ (and similarly for $b$).

But what if we relax the requirement that $f$ be defined at $a$ and $b$ and assume it only has one-sided limits there? So let me phrase this:

If a function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $(a, b)$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to b^-} f(x)$, then $f'$ is $0$ somewhere on $(a,b)$.

Is this true?

Comment: What you are stating allows the continuation of $c$ to a function $d$ which is continuous on $[a,b]$. Applying Rolle's theorem to $d$, you can then use the fact that they coincide on $(a,b)$ to draw conclusions about $c$. It's a veil on Rolle's theorem, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \to b^-}f(x) = c$ (say), then we can define a function $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ by
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} c & x = a {\rm \ \ or \ \ } x = b\\ f(x) & x \in (a,b)\end{cases}$$
This function $g$ is continuous! Then we can apply Rolle's theorem to $g$ to get the statement you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, extend the domain of $f$ to $[a,b]$ and apply the original result.